# Pigrrl 2 using pi 3, pitft 2.8 shutdown button

Tags: pi-3, pitft, shutdown

I have an unused button on the pitft screen that I want to use as a shutdown button. I tried the steps on adafruit but it just won't work. I've figured out hotkeys but not how to trigger a safe shutdown. Can anyone help me out? I'm still a noob

Comment: There is an excellent tutorial in the [MagPi Magazine](https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/) that explains how to [Add an Off Switch to Power Down Your PI](https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/off-switch-raspberry-pi/). You should be able to modify the instructions to make use of the unused button on pitft screen.